# twitter search api not returning exact phrase results everytime

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

The twitter search api is not returning tweets that only have an exact phrase. I'm using the quotes as the documentation specifies https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Here is what my search looks like

```
search_phrase = 'puppies'
tweet_results = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='"{}"'.format(search_phrase), lang = 'en', count = 100).items(1000)]
```

of the 1000 tweets 46 of them do not contain "puppies" here is some example output below. Perhaps "puppies" is located somewhere else in the tweet object? like maybe in the users about section of their profile. below are some bad responses.

RT @3_Beards: Oh yeah! @SiliconDrinkabt is growing! Welcoming @DrinkaboutTLV to the family with more on the way!

That moment when you forget that you're not the important person for them

RT @3_Beards: Oh yeah! @SiliconDrinkabt is growing! Welcoming @DrinkaboutTLV to the family with more on the way!

those were just a few of the bad results.

Comment: Can you show one example ? I think your code is fine.

Comment: added some examples. I can't find any errors in my code. Curious if this is just a problem with the api